# Delete previous sessions if login from new device MEANJS

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, meanjs, express-session

I want to remove previous session from MongoStore/sessionStore if a user login from new device. MEANJS is using

> express-session
>   connect-mongo

to store sessions in mongodb. I did search on it but could not find a solution to fetch the list of sessions from db. Please help me here

```
MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session),
favicon = require('serve-favicon'),

    module.exports.initSession = function (app, db) {
  // Express MongoDB session storage
  app.use(session({
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true,
    secret: config.sessionSecret,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: config.sessionCookie.maxAge,
      httpOnly: config.sessionCookie.httpOnly,
      secure: config.sessionCookie.secure && config.secure.ssl
    },
    key: config.sessionKey,
    store: new MongoStore({
      mongooseConnection: db.connection,
      collection: config.sessionCollection
    })
  }));
};
```

Comment: Well, if you remove common session, then people have to relogin every time they change device, with common session, they stay logged in from browser and phone at the same time

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly ok can u show me some code for guidance and where should i need to have remove common session code?

Answer (score 1):

This should work, at least it's a good starting point for you

```
var async = require('async'); //npm install async --save
exports.removeSessionsForUser = function(req, res, next) {
    var userId = req.user ? req.user.id : undefined;
    if (!userId)
        return next(new Error('No user found in req. Exiting'));

    var store = req.sessionStore;
    var sessionsColl = store.db.collection('sessions');

    sessionsColl.find({
        'session.user': userId,
        // we are tryin to remove all sessions, you can leave current
        // '_id': { '$ne': req.sessionID }
    }, { _id : 1 }, function (err, userSessions) {
        async.each(userSessions, function (userSession, cb) {
            store.destroy(userSession._id, cb);
        }, function(notDone) {
            if(notDone)
                return next(new Error(notDone));

            res.send('ok');
        });
    });
}
```

This uses [`async.each`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each), which is

```
async.each(Array, function(item, callback) {/* iterate */}, function(error) {/* end */});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help let me check this solution and get back to you. Thanks again

Comment: @ZaidIqbal note: **people have to relogin every time they change device**

Comment: userSession._id, _id is undefined getting error in this line

Comment: Yes,This is what I need that people needs to login again every time they change device.

Comment: log it, see what fields it has, maybe userSessions is stringified id itself like ['id1', 'id2']

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/hzljfjpfp/

you can check this object image here

Comment: please check the posted image and help in that how can we iterate and delete particular session from this object

Comment: check the `s` field, probably it's it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128676/discussion-between-zaid-iqbal-and-medet-tleukabiluly).

Answer (score 1):

Finally with the help I would be able solve the issue
Here is my code

```
    exports.logoutFromPreviousDevices = function (req, res) {
  var userId = req.query.userid;
  if (!userId)
    return res.status(400).send({
      message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage('No user found in input request')
    });

  var store = req.sessionStore;
  var sessionsColl = store.db.collection('sessions');

  sessionsColl.find({
    // 'session.passport.user': userId,
    // we are tryin to remove all sessions, you can leave current
    // '_id': { '$ne': req.sessionID }
  }, function (err, userSessions) {
    if (userSessions !== null) {
      userSessions.toArray(function (a, sessionsData) {
        sessionsData.forEach(function (element, index) {
          var data = JSON.parse(element.session);
          if (element._id !== req.sessionID && req.query.userid === data.passport.user) {
            store.destroy(element._id, function (destroyerr, dat) {
              if (destroyerr)
                return res.status(400).send({
                  message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(destroyerr)
                });
              res.jsonp({ status: 'Previous session deleted' });
            });
          }
        });
      });
    } else {
      res.jsonp({ status: 'No session found' });
    }
  });
};
```